# Tikz left margin indentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, indentation

Is there a better way to remove the indentation of a tikz figure?
What I have so far is this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

% \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[titlepagecolor] (0, -4) rectangle (15, -8); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I don't use `noindent` there is a small white space to the left, which I want to avoid to make a big rectangle across the page

Comment: I would use a `titlepage` environment for something like this. (I'm assuming it is a fancy title, judging by the name of the colour used.) And then change the indentation within that environment e.g. use `flushleft` or `\centering` or set `\parindent` to `0pt` or whatever. EDIT: Actually, I would use the `titling` package to help with this.

Comment: Or you could also specify the absolute position on the page. There's a package/library which you can use to get additional locations i.e. not just things like `current page.west` but coordinates defined relative to `text area` and so on. Take a look at `titling` and `tikzpagenodes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine the invocation of `\tikzpicture` to prepend itself with a `\noindent` which will alleviate the need for you to do it manually each time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\svtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\noindent\svtikzpicture}
\begin{document}
% \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill (0, -4) rectangle (15, -8); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```